# Pagina não carrega permanentemente com o comando .load (jQuery) do meu script (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Após eu clicar no elemento a parte de dentro do meu Dasboard não carrega da forma que eu esperava.

**Antes de clicar:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Me parece** que o script corta sozinho o `.load` já que ele carrega a página por um segundo e depois o main fica branco novamente.

**Depois de clicar:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Script que estou usando:

```
  document.getElementById("botao1").onclick = function(){BoardToMiddle1()};
  function BoardToMiddle1() {
      $("#div1").load("IndexHome.php");
  }
```

Elemento que após clicar, carrega o script:

```
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link text-white" href="" id="botao1" onclick="BoardToMiddle1"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">home</i>Página Inicial</a>
```

Main: (fiz a div para testar se era o main que estava bugando)

```
        <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100" id="main1">
        <div id="div1"></div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `<a>` com `href` vazio irá recarregar a página atual. Você precisa cancelar o evento do click no `<a>` enviando o evento para a função e usar `event.preventDefault()`:

```
document.getElementById("botao1").onclick = function(event){BoardToMiddle1(event)};
function BoardToMiddle1(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#div1").load("IndexHome.php");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo, não conhecia essa função e não reparei que era isso que estava empacando meu código. Revisei várias vezes, foi muito útil.